# Credit card number using AES counter mode encryption

Tags: encryption, aes

I want to encrypt credit card numbers. I want to apply AES counter mode because it supports arbitrary length. I want to send only the ciphertext and key; I don't want to send an IV along with the ciphertext.

Is it secure to use only a one time key and static IV? If so, what is the best way to generate 128 bit one time key? How many number of 128 bit one keys can be generated?

Comment: What's the problem of sending the IV along with the ciphertext? It can be public.

Comment: Should be migrated to IT security web site (sorry, I had answered before I thought of that in my afternoon break).

Answer (score 0):

A one time key with static IV is indeed secure. An IV / nonce needs only be unique for the same key. The best way to generate a one time key for AES is to simply use a special class such as a key factory or - if that's not available - a *cryptographically secure* random number generator to generate just 16 random bytes. Note that there are more ways available in transport protocols, most notably the Diffie-Hellman key agreement protocol (+ KBKDF).

You can generate as many keys as you want, just don't send them unencrypted.